# My Google Chrome shortcut Ctrl+Shift+M is not working

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

My Google Chrome shortcut   Ctrl + Shift + M is not working

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/shortcuts

It works in Firefox but not in Chrome, any idea?

When I use the shortcut, my user profile shows up as a pop up.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, it's working but the shortcut is being caught by the normal window browser instead of the Chrome Developer Tools window.

For the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> shortcut to really open/toggle the *Device toolbar/mode* (instead of opening the user profile popup), **you need to be focused on the Chrome Developer Tools window**.
This is a PITA in my opinion.

### Explanation

This happens because this same shortcut is used to open this user profile selection popup (as described [under Google Chrome feature shortcuts](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179)):

> Log in a different user or browse as a Guest: **Ctrl + Shift + m**

Lastly, it seems that there is still no way to disable Chrome shortcuts, but only override them by assigning them to extensions.
You can read more about this on [this article](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3177326/chrome-ctrl-shift-q.html).

Answer (score 0):

Open the Elements panel in Google Chrome <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>